# Prove that $ \bigcup_i U_i \subset \bigcup_i V_i \Longrightarrow ? \sum_i \mathrm{diam} \ U_i \le \sum_i \mathrm{diam} \ V_i $

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $ U_1, U_2, U_3, \dots $ and $ V_1, V_2, V_3, \dots  $ be subsets of $X$ which is a metric space.

Is it generally true that if $$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} U_i \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} V_i, $$
then
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{diam} \ U_i \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathrm{diam} \ V_i?  $$

I have failed many times by presenting similar arguments based on intuition. First, I thought that diameter is an outer measure but later I realized that it fails with subadditivity.  How could such statements be justified more rigorously?

Edit: I am especially interested in the case where $ U_1, U_2, \dots, U_n $   are disjoint and $U_i = \emptyset $ for $i>n$.

Comment: What if all $U_i$ are the same but $V_1 = U_1$ while $V_i =\emptyset$ for $i > 1$? This shows that you need at least some disjointedness assumption.

Comment: why no mention of the ambient space? i'm guessing it's a metric space but i don't think we should infer something like this from the tags alone...

Comment: @BCLC I thought that diameter can be defined only in metric spaces.

Comment: @PhoemueX That's a good point, thank you! The case I am interested in actually assumes that there are only finitely many $U_i $s which are disjoint. So here it would mean that finitely many $U_1, U_2, \dots, U_n $ are disjoint and $U_i = \emptyset $ for $i>n$. Would that be enough for the statement to hold?

Comment: mathslover, why so little imagination? XD just now i invented something called BCLC space where subsets can have diameter but BCLC space isn't a metric space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler example would be $V_1 = [0,1]$ and $U_1 = (0,2/3)$, and $U_2 = (1/3,1)$.

Comment: I did not do something like this because of a comment suggesting that disjoint sets were desired.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not.
Let our set be $X:=\{0,1,2,3\}$ in the line.  Then consider two disjoint covers.  First, $\{U_1\}$ where $U_1$ = $X$.
Second, $\{V_1,V_2\}$ where $V_1 = \{0,2\}$ and $V_2 = \{1,3\}$.  So
$$
\bigcup U_i = \bigcup V_i = X
$$
and
$$\sum_i\operatorname{diam}(U_i) = \operatorname{diam} U_1 = 3
\\
\sum_i\operatorname{diam}(V_i) 
= \operatorname{diam} V_1 + \operatorname{diam} V_2 = 2+2=4.
$$

---

In $\mathbb R^2$ we can do such a counterexample consisting of convex sets.